# "Binary rejected" application in the AppStore

Tags: ios

I have a problem with the publication app in the App Store. Support for iTunes immediately rejects the application, and "Code-Level Support" have not answered from two months.

iTunes Support reply below message to brief the rejection:

> Performance - 2.3
>
> We were unable to install the app on iPhone 6s and iPad Air. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on an iPhone 6s and iPad Air.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are required and false if they must not be present on the device.

App works fine on iPhone 6s and iPad Air using Xcode "Build Configuration" => "Release"

info.plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>wHere is 24 - POI Search</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Zezwól, aby móc zrobić zdjęcie.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Aplikacja wymaga dostępu do GPS, inaczej nie będzie poprawnie działać.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Aplikacja wymaga dostępu do GPS, inaczej nie będzie poprawnie działać.</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Zezwól, aby móc wybrać zdjęcie z galerii zdjęć.</string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>MainApp</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
    <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>AppleLanguages</key>
    <array>
        <string>en</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Why do you require `armv7` in `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`? That precludes all of the newer iOS devices.

Comment: @rmaddy I did not change the value in the key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities.` The project was generated on the latest Xcode. What should I set the application to run on all devices from iOS 9? Thanks for you reply.

Comment: Yeah. You need to add one more in the list armv64

Comment: @GeneCode - thank for you reply and help, but http://imgur.com/2EGpAIc (when sending to appstore)

Answer (score 1):

`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key is essentially saying to install ONLY on devices with armv7 processors. Try removing the `armv7` key from the `info.plist`

Comment: i sent app to the testflight and i can not install app on iPhone 6 Plus "Could not intall ..." and iPhone 5 is incompatible with app.